# Windows Explorer context menu item ids

Tags: winapi, contextmenu, windows-explorer

Using `::GetMenuItemInfo()` I see that on my Win 8.1 x 64 'Delete' menu item ID is equal to decimal 18 and 'Properties' ID is equal to 20. Are they the same on any Windows and where are they defined in the SDK headers?

**UPDATE**

I'd like to use `TrackPopupMenu` to show the system menu for some files inside my app, but I want to override some of items such as 'Delete'. How can I check whether an item #i (where i is an index from 0 to item count) is the 'Delete' item to change its id to my own and handle it later? If IDs are constant, it seems to be pretty simple, but otherwise...

Comment: I don't see any reason why they would be defined anywhere, or expected to be stable. You don't need to know these values.

Comment: The how can I track the system context menu in my app, overriding just 2 of them? I've seen a program, which does that.

Comment: What does that mean? Overriding two of them? Anyway, you didn't ask about tracking anything, or overriding anything. You asked about menu item IDs.

Comment: 2 of items: 'Delete' and 'Properties' as I wrote in the question ))

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, was writing in hurry. I've updated the question, I hope it's now more correct. Thank you for pointing me to its low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don`t use menu item ID for command identification. Command IDs can be different in different time even on the same PC. If you want to override any menu item you must analyse verb of command instead of ID. Verbs are always the same.

When you have IContextMenu of object enum menu items and call IContextMenu.GetCommandString function with GCS_VERBA or GCS_VERBW parameter. When GetCommandString return you 'delete' string - at this position you have Delete command. When GetCommandString return you 'properties' string - at this position you have Properties command.

Comment: Just looked at Classic Shell sources — its author did the same.